# pm-hibernate don't work properly on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: power-management, 20.04, hibernate

On my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, `sudo pm-hibernate` does not work properly. After installing `uswsusp` package, when I execute the command, it just saves the state to swap. But it does not power off my PC. I have to use my power button to force power off. Although when I power on it again, it successfully gets back from hibernation. So I configure systemctl to use `pm-hibernate` when I execute `systemctl hibernate`. So the problem is it does not automatically power off on executing `sudo pm-hibernate` or `systemctl hibernate`.

Update:
This is the output of `pm-is-supported` :

```
$ pm-is-supported
pm-is-supported [--suspend | --hibernate | --suspend-hybrid ]
```

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, but the problem still persists. I have also tried `s2disk` , but same situation.

Comment: What does `pm-is-supported` report? All 3 options.

Comment: @waltinator Yes